# How do I make a radio button Yes/No field mandatory?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I have to make a Yes/No answer mandatory. The project owner wants a 'checkbox' which would involve some ugly with a tri-state checkbox, or two radio buttons. the latter seems the neatest, but I have no idea how to make it so that only one of the checkboxes must be checked. My only other idea is to stuff the checkboxes and use a dropdown.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use

```
[Required]
public bool? YesNo { get; set; }
```

In the ViewModel and make sure it's initially null.

Bool is by default false. By using nullable bool?, you set it's initial state to null.

Comment: Will MVC render this as a tristate or double-radio-button control? Won't this render as a regular checkbox so on postback, you still don't know wether you receive a null (ths user did not select the checkbox because he did not want to enter a value) or a false (the user explicitly choose not to check it?)

Comment: @Michel I must verify this, but it seems to render as a dropdown with three values.